# How to map id with name in presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have the below data in table1

| id | marks | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 78 | 100 |
| 2 | 20 | 50 |

and I know `1 -> Sam` and `2 -> Joe`

I want to show

| id | percentage | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 78 | Sam |
| 2 | 40 | Joe |

Not sure where to start when I have the id -> map as static map

Comment: _"Not sure where to start when I have the id -> map as static map"_ - can you please explain? In what form you have it static?

Comment: id/name is a static list of 5 entries, marks will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know 1 -> Sam and 2 -> Joe following is possible :

```
SELECT
    id,
    marks,
    total,
    CASE id
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Sam'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Joe'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END AS name,
    (marks / total) * 100.0 AS percentage
FROM
    table1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have some kind of static data that is not a part of your dataset, you can hardcode it in the query by using [`WITH` clause](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#with-clause):

```sql
with static_map(id, name) as(
    values (1, 'Sam'),
    (2, 'Joe')
)

select t.id, t.marks * 100.0 / t.total, m.name
from table1 t
left join static_map m on t.id = m.id;
```